# firmware-sof-signed was in 21.10 impish but is not found in 22.04 LTS jammy

Tags: package-management

How do I get a package that was in a previous version of Ubuntu that is not present in a new release?  Is the only option to go to the source and build it?

The package `firmware-sof-signed` is not found under 22.04 LTS "jammy".  It was present (and required by my system) under 21.10 "impish".

Under 21.10 impish:

```
~$ apt list | grep firmware-sof-signed
firmware-sof-signed/impish,impish 1.7-1 all
```

Nothing is returned by the command under 22.04 LTS jammy.

Comment: I see it via `firmware-sof-signed | 2.0-1ubuntu2 | jammy/restricted          | all` - do you have that repository enabled?   Why is there mention of *kinetic* or 22.10 in your question? (typo?)  Your `apt list` will only search on your enabled repositories; my copy/paste using another command that searches all releases enabled as it's normal for users to be using a different release to my own on this site.

Comment: @guiverc Yes, I just found this as well.  Adding the restricted repository resolved this. 
And, yes, the 22.10 was a typo.  Thanks for noting it.

Comment: You can write your own answer if you'd like (get some more *rep*), but FYI the command/script I used to get my paste was `rmadison` (from package `devscripts`), useful as most users on this site won't be using my release (*it'll look beyond my own software lists for my current release*)

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for the script and reference to `rmadison`.  It will come in handy for the future.  Since my issue was resolved by just finding that the package had been moved and adding the restricted repository, I chose to share that as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learned something new: Checking the [packages list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/kernel/) I found that it had been moved from [multiverse] in 21.10 impish to [restricted] in 22.04 LTS jammy.  Using `sudo add-apt-repository restricted` in the install script resolved the issue.